# Stats for forest cover change over 10 years in R

Tags: raster, r, sf, sp

I am rather new to GIS and I don't know how to perform the following operation: [ R programming language]
I am developing a project evaluating forest cover change over 10 years (2010-2020) for a specific area in the state of São Paulo/ Brazil. I have this area as a shapefile, and I have managed to clip this area from the raster of forest cover change in a single year (I can sure do it for the other years). I then proceeded to extract the value of the resulting raster to inspect the output. However, I don't know where to go from there to compile the forest cover change data over the years and compute statistics. The output from the extraction is a list I cannot interpret. Does anyone know how to do this? So far, I have used the sf, sp and raster packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extracting you just need to get the area of each class, which is resolution_x*resolution_y (or resolution^2 if the same) by the number of pixels of that class.

In the following code data is grouped by year and class, after the extract part you already did.

```r
library(raster)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

rs = stack()   # build a random stack just to use for the example
for(i in 1:8) {
  m = matrix(sample(1:8, 100, TRUE), nrow = 10)
  r = raster(m, xmn = 700000, xmx = 700100, ymn = 2100000, ymx = 2100100, crs = "+proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
  r = as.factor(r)
  names(r) = paste0("year", i)
  rs = stack(rs, r)
}

sample_pol = st_as_sfc("POLYGON ((700013 2100005, 700050 2100005, 700050 2100070, 700013 2100070, 700013 2100005))")
sample_pol = as(sample_pol, "Spatial")

rs_extract = raster::extract(rs, sample_pol) # you already did this part

as.data.frame(rs_extract) %>% 
 gather() %>%         # change the shape of the data frame
 group_by(key, value) %>% summarise(cover_area = n()*100) %>% # 10*10 m resolution
 ggplot(aes(key, cover_area, fill = as.factor(value))) + geom_col() + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Class")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I don't understand all of it though: where do I retrieve the values in this line of code: 
r = raster(m, xmn = 700000, xmx = 700100, ymn = 2100000, ymx = 2100100, crs = "+proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")

Comment: That's just a sample raster I built for demonstrating the code, I wrote them by hand from XY values

Comment: Kudos, that is a nice graph, lots of information in a small space.